# Lazy collections cause crashes with "unstable" filters & sorts

Tags: swift

I just saw a thread that asked about lazy collections. They look like this:

```
let array = Array(1...10).lazy
```

The docs say this about a lazy collection: "A collection containing the same elements as a Base collection, but on which some operations such as map and filter are implemented lazily."

The idea is avoiding lots of intermediate collections. If you have code like this:

let array = 1...10
    .filter { $0 %2 == 0 }
    .sorted { $0 < $1 }
    .map { String($0) }

Then each step in the code creates an intermediate array. For large arrays, this can make for a large memory footprint.

In experimenting with lazy, though, I found that if one or more of the steps in handling the lazy collection returns different results each time it's executed, it can cause problems/crashes. Consider this code:

```
@discardableResult func timeTest() -> Double {
    let start = Date()
    let array = 1...10
    let random = array
        .lazy
        .map { (value) -> UInt32 in
            let random = arc4random_uniform(100)
            print("Mapping", value, "to random val \(random)")
            return random
        }
        .filter {
            let result = $0 < 50
            print("  Testing \($0) < 50", result)
            return result
        }
        .map { (val: UInt32) -> NSNumber in
            print("    Mapping", val, "to NSNumber")
            return NSNumber(value: val)
        }
        .compactMap { (number) -> String? in
            print("      Mapping", number, "to String")
            return formatter.string(from: number)
        }
        .sorted { (lhv, rhv) -> Bool in //--> This is the line that crashes
            print("        Sorting strings")
            return (lhv.compare(rhv, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending)
    }

    random.enumerated().forEach { print("String[\($0.0)] = \($0.1)") }

    let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(start)

    print("Completed in ", String(format: "%0.3f", elapsed), " seconds")
    return elapsed
}
```

That code maps values from 1...100 to random values, filters out values < 50, sorts the remaining values, converts them to strings, and prints them.

That might yield output like this:

```
Mapping 1 to random val 47
  Testing 47 < 50 true
Mapping 1 to random val 57
    Mapping 57 to NSNumber
      Mapping 57 to String
Mapping 2 to random val 6
  Testing 6 < 50 true
Mapping 3 to random val 33
  Testing 33 < 50 true
Mapping 4 to random val 21
  Testing 21 < 50 true
Mapping 5 to random val 2
  Testing 2 < 50 true
Mapping 6 to random val 75
  Testing 75 < 50 false
Mapping 7 to random val 45
  Testing 45 < 50 true
Mapping 8 to random val 72
  Testing 72 < 50 false
Mapping 9 to random val 1
  Testing 1 < 50 true
Mapping 10 to random val 67
  Testing 67 < 50 false
Mapping 2 to random val 3
  Testing 3 < 50 true
Mapping 2 to random val 3
    Mapping 3 to NSNumber
      Mapping 3 to String
Mapping 3 to random val 6
  Testing 6 < 50 true
Mapping 3 to random val 86
    Mapping 86 to NSNumber
      Mapping 86 to String
Mapping 4 to random val 72
  Testing 72 < 50 false
Mapping 5 to random val 2
  Testing 2 < 50 true
Mapping 5 to random val 73
    Mapping 73 to NSNumber
      Mapping 73 to String
Mapping 6 to random val 31
  Testing 31 < 50 true
Mapping 6 to random val 53
    Mapping 53 to NSNumber
      Mapping 53 to String
Mapping 7 to random val 31
  Testing 31 < 50 true
Mapping 7 to random val 42
    Mapping 42 to NSNumber
      Mapping 42 to String
Mapping 8 to random val 41
  Testing 41 < 50 true
Mapping 8 to random val 23
    Mapping 23 to NSNumber
      Mapping 23 to String
Mapping 9 to random val 52
  Testing 52 < 50 false
Mapping 10 to random val 13
  Testing 13 < 50 true
Mapping 10 to random val 81
    Mapping 81 to NSNumber
      Mapping 81 to String
Mapping 1 to random val 84
  Testing 84 < 50 false
Mapping 2 to random val 1
  Testing 1 < 50 true
Mapping 2 to random val 82
    Mapping 82 to NSNumber
      Mapping 82 to String
Mapping 2 to random val 10
    Mapping 10 to NSNumber
      Mapping 10 to String
Mapping 3 to random val 58
  Testing 58 < 50 false
Mapping 4 to random val 98
  Testing 98 < 50 false
Mapping 5 to random val 12
  Testing 12 < 50 true
Mapping 5 to random val 9
    Mapping 9 to NSNumber
      Mapping 9 to String
Mapping 5 to random val 59
    Mapping 59 to NSNumber
      Mapping 59 to String
Mapping 6 to random val 49
  Testing 49 < 50 true
Mapping 6 to random val 29
    Mapping 29 to NSNumber
      Mapping 29 to String
Mapping 6 to random val 57
    Mapping 57 to NSNumber
      Mapping 57 to String
Mapping 7 to random val 20
  Testing 20 < 50 true
Mapping 7 to random val 87
    Mapping 87 to NSNumber
      Mapping 87 to String
Mapping 7 to random val 51
    Mapping 51 to NSNumber
      Mapping 51 to String
Mapping 8 to random val 2
  Testing 2 < 50 true
Mapping 8 to random val 93
    Mapping 93 to NSNumber
      Mapping 93 to String
Mapping 8 to random val 11
    Mapping 11 to NSNumber
      Mapping 11 to String
Mapping 9 to random val 18
  Testing 18 < 50 true
Mapping 9 to random val 47
    Mapping 47 to NSNumber
      Mapping 47 to String
Mapping 9 to random val 96
    Mapping 96 to NSNumber
      Mapping 96 to String
Mapping 10 to random val 10
  Testing 10 < 50 true
Mapping 10 to random val 44
    Mapping 44 to NSNumber
      Mapping 44 to String
Mapping 10 to random val 76
    Mapping 76 to NSNumber
      Mapping 76 to String
```

Followed by an index out of range crash.

Note that when a value passes the test in the filter, the original map to a random number is invoked again. Also note that sometimes the repeat mapping to a random value happens out of order.

I'm guessing that each higher-order function step re-evaluates the previous step, and since the random number step returns different values each time, and then the filter step returns different numbers of results each time, it gets confused.

Does anybody reading this have specific knowledge about what's going on?

Comment: Could you define `formatter` please? a `NumberFormatter()` I suppose?

Comment: Your guess is right. Lazy collection keeps the original collection and applies each `map` or `filter` to the original element on demand.

Comment: I suspect `sort` is entirely to blame. Every other step takes one input and produces zero or one outputs. `sort` needs to compare various values so it must be causing the recalculation of previous values.

Comment: Yes, `formatter` is just a `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: If you move the `.lazy` to after the map to random numbers, it no longer crashes. That makes sense because then the array contents no longer change, so re-filtering and re-sorting will yield the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that when `sorted(by:)` tries to be executed the count of the array differs. `filter` changes the count of the resulting array and that interfers with the way `sorted(by:)` works.

`sorted(by:)` internally calls `sort(by:)`:

```
@inlinable
public func sorted(
  by areInIncreasingOrder:
    (Element, Element) throws -> Bool
) rethrows -> [Element] {
  var result = ContiguousArray(self) 
  try result.sort(by: areInIncreasingOrder)
  return Array(result)
}
```

Using a contiguous array makes the sorting faster.

Jumping to the [definition](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift) of `sort(by:)`:

```
@inlinable
public mutating func sort(
  by areInIncreasingOrder: (Element, Element) throws -> Bool
) rethrows {
  let didSortUnsafeBuffer = try _withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupported {
  buffer -> Void? in
    try buffer.sort(by: areInIncreasingOrder)
  }
  if didSortUnsafeBuffer == nil {
    try _introSort(within: startIndex..<endIndex, by: areInIncreasingOrder)
  }
}
```

We can see that it calls the internal functions `_introSort(within:,by:)` and its actual implementation `_introSortImpl(within:,by:,depthLimit:)`.

Swift, like .Net and C++, uses the *Introsort algorithm* to sort elements of an array. Which a hybrid of Quicksort and heapSort: It partitions the array by choosing a pivot (median-of-3). Finally, when it reaches a depth of 0, it switches to a heapSort. The details of the *Introsort* algorithm used by `sort` are described in this [paper](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gp/introsort.ps).

In-place sorting a contiguous array calls [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3d7dfc232b9d7dd37c0fe5749b4617e00cf92ec6/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArray.swift) function:

```
public mutating func replaceSubrange<C>(
  _ subrange: Range<Int>,
  with newElements: C
)
```

Internally this calls [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7c0ff47487e8a17441b84a7a84bc6520ecd1b362/stdlib/public/core/ArrayShared.swift):

```
internal mutating func _arrayOutOfPlaceReplace<C: Collection>(
  _ bounds: Range<Int>,
  with newValues: C,
  count insertCount: Int
)
```

Which makes [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7c0ff47487e8a17441b84a7a84bc6520ecd1b362/stdlib/public/core/ArrayShared.swift) final check:

```
internal func _expectEnd<C: Collection>(of s: C, is i: C.Index)
```

If the size of the array change whilst being sorted, then an error will be raised with this message

```
"invalid Collection: count differed in successive traversals"
```

Unlike mapping or filtering, sorting an array requires having an array of constant size and constant values while it's being sorted.

Comment: The thing that isn't obvious is that during the sort, it re-runs the map(to random) and filter steps, so the array contents (and even the number of elements in the array) change out from under the sort. I'm curious how this works in memory, since arrays are value types.

Comment: @Carpsen90 So making `sorted` a separate step fixes things? But is sorted not called in the end, after all other functions have finished? Where does it get the wrong array count from? Is it taking it from the lazy array before all other steps run through, and after all steps finished lazy has a differenz size? Taking the size immediately instead of waiting till executed seems counter-intuitive to me, no?